# Meaning of Objects.deepEquals method

Tags: java, equals, equality

The question is about static methods `Objects.deepEquals` class (since `Java 7`):

```
public static boolean deepEquals(Object a, Object b) {
    if (a == b)
        return true;
    else if (a == null || b == null)
        return false;
    else
        return Arrays.deepEquals0(a, b);
}
```

As it said in `javadoc` of this method:

> Returns true if the arguments are deeply equal to each other and false
>   otherwise.

What I do not understand: where is the **depth** of comparison? As we can see inside its implementation it just does references comparison, and inside `Arrays.deepEquals0(a, b)` for simple `Object` and `Object` arguments it invokes 
just: `eq = e1.equals(e2);`. So in what kind of sense two objects are **deeply** equal?

Comment: You are talking about the class Objects not Object

Comment: I guess it has the same meaning as a deep copy. You do not compare references, but rather data behind the references.

Comment: @raupach Great! Thanks a lot, my mistake. But question is still actual

Comment: the Javadoc of `Objects.deepEquals` defines quite clearly what it means with deeply equal

Comment: In case you compare `Object[]`, there is a recursive call to `deepEquals`

Comment: @AlexisC. in this case why does this method exists if it just deep comparison only for arrays?

Comment: If you get back one or two arguments with the compile time type `Object` and you know it can possibly be arrays, the `deepEquals` method does all the instance of checks for you. I've never used it but some can imagine a real use case I guess (for instance with a dependency to a third-party library).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The comparison would be *deep*, if you passed Array objects.

Non-array objects will not be evaluated deeper than what you get with `equals` .

So the depth isn't relevant in your case :

> Two null values are deeply equal. **If both arguments are arrays**, the
>   algorithm in Arrays.deepEquals is used to determine equality.
>   Otherwise, equality is determined by using the equals method of the
>   first argument.

Quoted from :

[Object.deepEquals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#deepEquals(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object))

Answer (score 5):

You can refer: [Your's Deeply - Why Arrays.deepEquals When We Have Arrays.equals](https://dzone.com/articles/yours-deeply-why)

> Arrays.deepEquals looks really deep
>
> From the source, we could understand that Arrays.deepEquals
>
> 1. Loops through the input arrays, gets each pair
> 2. Analyses the type of each pair
> 3. Delegates the equal deciding logic to one of the overloaded
>      Arrays.equals if they are one of the primitive arrays
> 4. Delegates recursively to Arrays.deepEquals if it is an Object array
> 5. Calls the respective object’s equals, for any other object